# Service not destroyed (or refreshed, cleaned...) when is not necessary

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-observables

I have a component with a service injected (my data store) which feed data from other http service. You can access to this component through a lazy loading route configuration (loadChildren).

When a user logs out (to another different route) and immediately logs in with a different user (a person can mantain two user), the store service serve the same data before (old user), when I think that it should charge new data (new user).

I think that service should be "destroyed" when the user logs out since the service observer is destroyed (in ngOnDestroy) and the injection is not necessary in such way that the service is built again.

I know that the component can obtain from service new fresh data with another method, but I think the service already should be obtaining data from Constructor-ngOnInt. The problem is that the service is not destroyed, clerared... and the data remains from old user.

Here is my code.

Component

```
constructor(
public busquedasStore: BusquedasStore) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.busquedasSubs = this.busquedasStore.busquedas.subscribe(b => {
   this.busquedas = b;
})

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.busquedasSubs.unsubscribe();
}
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
import { UserService } from '../../core/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class BusquedasStore {

busquedas$: BehaviorSubject<{}[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

constructor(
 public userService:UserService
)  {
 this.cargarDatosIni();
}

cargarDatosIni() {
 this.userService.me().subscribe((res) => {
   let busquedas:{}[] = res.user.busqueda;
   this.busquedas$.next(busquedas);
 },err => {
   console.log(err);
 });
}

get busquedas(): Observable<{}[]> {
 return this.busquedas$;
}
```

Comment: Services are singletons, their lifecycle is different to components. You have a behaviour subject which replays the previous value to new subscribers, which in this case (until you trigger a new fetch) is the previous user's data. You should call `cargarDatosIni` when the user logs in to get the new data.

Answer (score 5):

Since the names of your items in your code is in Spanish, I don't have additional context, but I can pick up the gist of what you're doing.

**Your current implementation**

Your service uses a BehaviorSubject to 'store' information about the current user after the person logs in. The service retrieves that information itself when it is created. In your component that you show on logging in, you subscribe to that BehaviorSubject to get at that user data, and then you unsubscribe on ngDestroy of that component, so you expect that the service would be destroyed as well, so that when you log in with someone else, the service would be recreated fresh with that new user's information.

**The misunderstanding**

Unfortunately, your understanding of `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` when it comes to BehaviorSubjects is inaccurate, which is (partially) why you're not getting the behaviour you expect. A BehaviorSubject can support many different subscribers at the same time, and as such, one subscriber unsubscribing to it will not cause it to stop producing values (or clear any existing value it has already produced).

The other misunderstanding is around how services are created and destroyed. If a service is provided by an NgModule, it will only be created once and never reinitialized after that. If, however, you provide the service at the component level, then the service shares the lifetime of the component that provided it and will be created and destroyed at the same time as the component.

**The solutions**

You have two basic options. The quickest to implement may be to simply provide your service at the component level ONLY. So, if you have a providers configuration at the NgModule level for your service, remove it, and only add it to your component.

The second option, which I think might be the better long term option, is to change your service so that it does not fetch the user information in its constructor, but instead lets the component make that call. That way, whenever a new user logs in, a new call will be made to get the user info and the service will always reflect the information of the current user.

So,

```
@Injectable()
export class BusquedasStore {

busquedas$: BehaviorSubject<{}[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

constructor(
 public userService:UserService
)  {
 //this.cargarDatosIni();  <-- remove this line
}

......
```

and in your component,

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.busquedasStore.cargarDatosIni();   // <--- add your service initialization call
 this.busquedasSubs = this.busquedasStore.busquedas.subscribe(b => {
   this.busquedas = b;
})
```

Comment: Yes, my current solution is your secod solution. Your "first misunderstanding" is not correct in my case, I think I undestand the behaviorsubjects, I know this obsevarble will not cause stop it producing values... but your "second misunderstanding" is correct and is the solution to my doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether this will solve your particular problem but the services to be injected are taken by Injector from a providers hierarchy, so you can register the provider on `NgModule` level and / or also register it on a `Component` level.

```
@Component({
  // ...
  providers: [BusquedasStore]
  // ...
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

and that would mean that every time new component gets created it would receive a new instance of a service (in fact it would destroy the old one when component gets destroyed); it will override the current `NgModule` `BusquedasStore` service if you specify it there as well.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html for more info

Comment: Yes this is the correct response. I thought they were destroyed by not being used even though they were injected at module level

Comment: @JavierRB at the module level they are injected once per module instance (the same like with the component actually). However since there can be only one module instance per application the module is not getting destroyed => the service is not getting destroyed as well